# vim FIGlet question: "-w76--" after every output

Tags: vimscript

I love the plugin [vim-FIGlet](https://github.com/fadein/vim-FIGlet) but I every time when I run `:FIGlet ...`, it always produces a text shape of `-w76--` right after. For example, this is the output of `:FIGlet demo`:

```
     _                                        _____ __                  
  __| | ___ _ __ ___   ___        __      __ |___  / /_                 
 / _` |/ _ \ '_ ` _ \ / _ \   ____\ \ /\ / /    / / '_ \   _____ _____  
| (_| |  __/ | | | | | (_) | |_____\ V  V /    / /| (_) | |_____|_____| 
 \__,_|\___|_| |_| |_|\___/         \_/\_/    /_/  \___/
```

Is there a solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: If I understand the readme correctly, you enter the text in your buffer, visually select it and then execute `:FIGlet`. Arguments to the command are only for width, font etc, but not the text to print. It seems to be equivalent to  `!!figlet`.

Comment: @Ralf it will output the text to buffer

Comment: ```:r !figlet```

Comment: @David so does `!!figlet`. Write a line of text. Then hit `!!`. This will bring you to the command line, which will already contain `.!`. just type `figlet` and enter. The line in the buffer is replaced with the output of figlet.

Comment: @AlexKroll this works! thanks!

Comment: open an issue with that specific plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `:r !figlet demo` instead of that plugin, which works just as well:

```
     _                      
  __| | ___ _ __ ___   ___  
 / _` |/ _ \ '_ ` _ \ / _ \ 
| (_| |  __/ | | | | | (_) |
 \__,_|\___|_| |_| |_|\___/
```